# Installing Ubuntu on XPS 9500

Tags: xps

I would like to install Ubuntu on my XPS 15 (9500) to replace Windows completely. Is this possible and has anyone done so?
Thx.

Comment: Lots of people have installed Ubuntu on that particular Dell. If you would like to test "out-of-the-box compatibility", consider running the Live USB. This will be a good indicator of success.

Answer (score 1):

I have done with my XPS 9500. All working goods, only some issue about battery life.

### Some hints

#### prerequisite

Disable secure boot and Intel Rapid Storage Technology before installation

#### gnome tweaks

It allows you some extra conf like touchpad gestures
`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

#### fingerprint reader

```bsh
sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-dell.list << EOF
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-dell public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-dell public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-oem public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-oem public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville-melisa public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-somerville-melisa public
EOF'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9FDA6BED73CDC22
sudo apt update -qq

sudo apt install oem-somerville-melisa-meta libfprint-2-tod1-goodix oem-somerville-meta tlp-config -y

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boltgolt/howdy -y
sudo apt update -qq
sudo apt install howdy -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Inspiron 5481 2-in-1 and also an HP 15-DA0073MS that I have installed Ubuntu or Ubuntu based distro on and all installed without any problems. The  touchscreens work fine as well as the backlit keyboards, mouse, etc. I actually have had better luck with Ubuntu than I have had with Windows in compatibility and the drivers have been spot on. I would do like the other person suggests and just load the ISO onto a USB and try it out. You'll have to press the F9 during the boot process to change to the USB drive. I would highly recommend this OS over Windows any day.